# Angular 2 ajax load, and execute script tags

Tags: javascript, ajax, angular, typescript

I have a problem. It's AJAX load page, and script tags execution of that page.

```
.then(response => {

            let restr: string = response;



            restr = restr.replace(/(<head[^>]*)(?:[^])*?\/head>/ig, '')
                .replace(/(<(\/?)body([^>]*?)>)/g, '')
                .replace(/(<style[^>]*)(?:[^])*?\/style>/g, '')
                .replace(/(<(\/?)html([^>]*?)>)/g, '')
                .replace(/(<app-root[^>]*)(?:[^])*?\/app-root>/ig, '')
                .replace(/(<\?[\s\S]*?\?>)|(<!DOCTYPE\s+\w+\s+\[[\s\S]*?\]>)|(<!\w[\s\S]*?>)/g, '')
                .replace(/href\s*=\s*(?:")/ig, 'href="/#')
                .replace(/href\s*=\s*(?:')/ig, "href='/#");



            let scripts = restr.match(/\<scr[\s\S]*?ipt>/g);


            this.srcfield.nativeElement.innerHTML = '';


            scripts.forEach(value => {
                var element = document.createElement('script');

                var valstr = value.match(/"([^"]+)*"/g)[0]
                    .replace(/"|'([^"]+)*"|'/g, '')
                    .replace(/text\/javascript/g, '');

                element.src = valstr;

                this.srcfield.nativeElement.appendChild(element);
            })

            this.response = restr;


        })
```

How do you realize, `response` is answer from server, it's just HTML page provided by text. I make some operation on this page, and product it to current user page, without reloading.
But some tag `script` doesn't `load`, because it execute don't by order.
How can i `load script` tags to correctly

P.S The page which loaded, was generate by YII2 Framework

Answer (score 1):

you can use callback

```
function addScript( src,callback) {
  var script = document.createElement( 'script' );
  script.setAttribute( 'src', src );
  script.onload=callback;
  document.body.appendChild( s );
}
```